# How to use force:createRecord for a stand alone app or lightning out?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to use `force:createRecord` and it works okay in Lightning Experience, and S1 but but I get the following error message when I am using a stand alone app. If I preview the "**sampleCreateRecordApp.app**" I get the below error message:

> "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: c:sampleCreateRecord$controller$createRecord [Cannot read
>   property 'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:sampleCreateRecord$controller$createRecord}"

Below is the simple compoment I'm trying to get to work in a stand alone app (or lightning out). The [documentation link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_events.htm) [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_events.htm) alludes that they can be used outside of LEX or S1

If I try to extend the application with `extends="ltng:outApp"` the application does not render at all. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

**sampleLightningOutPage.page**

```
<apex:page >


    <script src="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
    <div id="sampleComponentDiv" />    

    <script> 
        $Lightning.use("c:sampleCreateRecordApp",function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:sampleCreateRecord",
                {},
                "sampleComponentDiv"
            );

        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**sampleCreateRecordApp.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <c:sampleCreateRecord/>

</aura:application>
```

**sampleCreateRecord.cmp**

```
 <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.createRecord }" />


</aura:component>
```

**sampleCreateRecord.js**

```
({
    createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Contact"
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: can you share your visualforce page code also?

Comment: I updated my post to include the visualforce page as well. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The `force:createRecord` feature is unsupported for ligtning out - as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation):

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, the Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

That means - not available on lightning out and therefore inside a visualforce page.

Comment: The documentation link you provided is not working. Can you please share the link again

Comment: @MonalisaDas updated!

Comment: wre you able to do it with any work arounds ?

Answer (score 0):

@Monalisa Das

You can find the updated documentation here - [force:createRecord Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation)